# android:save cropped image in file and read it on activity for result

Tags: android, save, crop, onactivityresult

I have a horrible problem with cropping photos in android.i wrote a code to crop image selected from gallery or captured by camera but image larger than 300px causes memory problems.now i need to save cropped image and read it  on activity for result method.
this my code but it reduces max image size to 300px:

```
try {


        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

           String filepath;
            File f = new File(picUri);
            filepath = f.getPath() ; 
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
            width=  bitmap.getWidth();
             height= bitmap.getHeight();
            if(width>299 || height>299)
            {
            if(width>=height)
                    {

                    height=(int)(((float)height/width)*299);

                    width=299;
                    }
            else if(width<height)
            {
                width=((float)width/height)*299;

                height=299;
            }
            }
       bitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)width, height, false);
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70,bos);

           bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
           byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

           //write the bytes in file
           try
           {
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
           fos.write(bitmapdata);
           fos.flush();
           fos.close();
           }
         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        finally
        {

        }



           Uri  contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");


            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);


        }

        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {




        }
    }
```

**and onactivityforresult method:**

```
             else  if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
             if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  

                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                 Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");





                 Intent i=new Intent(selectimage.this,MainActivity.class);
                 i.putExtra("bmp", selectedBitmap);
                 startActivity(i);
                 finish();
             }
        }
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: i try to import these libraries but every time i had problems with compile.can you guide me how to use?

Comment: Ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problems.